# Is there a Visual Studio Project Configuration Macro which defines DEBUG or RELEASE regardless of the Project Configuration Name?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, configuration, macros

I saw that its a very common thing to use the Visual Studio Macro called `$(Configuration)` for build file paths.

For example if you create a new Visual C++ Project in Visual Studio 2013 your default Property Sheet will look something like this:

[image: Default Visual Studio VC++ Property Sheet]

The `$(Configuration)` Macro is the Name of the current Project Configuration. If you do not rename your configurations or create new ones, you will be able to add `$(Configuration)` everywhere where you need to set either `Debug` or `Release`. This way, you can set a configuration property for **All Configurations** instead of going to every Release or Debug configuration and setting it separately.

But what if you decide to rename your configurations? And you want them to be built into the same `Release` or `Debug` directory instead of having a new folder for every configuration? Is there still a way to get a Macro or define one that says `Debug` or `Release` even if the configuration is named otherwise?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Exactly why would you want two configurations that write files to the same directory? That's just asking for trouble - constant rebuilding at best, linking together mismatched files at worst. What actual problem do you believe this will help you solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property sheets allow you to make 'User Defined Macros', which translate into configuration variables you can use in your project files. You would:

1. Create a two [property sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
2. In each, create a User Defined Macro (named say `ConfigurationType` - do not use `$` or `()` when creating it), in one property sheet, you'd set its value to `Debug` in one, and to `Release` in the other.
3. Attach the appropriate property sheet to each configuration in the Property Manager (View->Property Manager in the VS menu).
4. Use the `$(ConfigurationType)` (or whatever you name the macro), in your project properties, however you see fit - eg. instead of the `($Configuration)` macro in your case.

Property sheets are a much easier way to manage settings if you have a large number of configurations that share common properties. I use the described method frequently, for example with linking third party libraries, which commonly have only `Debug` and `Release` builds, while my project has numerous configurations.

#### Note:

Be careful when using this for your intermediate directory output however - if you have two configurations using the same one, then you may run into problems.